# SQL server smallmoney data type error

Tags: sql-server-2008, char

```
CREATE TABLE GroovyExps_Tgt
      (EMPNO                SMALLINT,
       FIRSTNAME            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       MIDINIT              CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
       LASTNAME             VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
       SALARY_INT           INT,
       SALARY_Decimal       DECIMAL,
       SALARY_Numeric       NUMERIC,
       SALARY_FLOAT         FLOAT(9), 
       SALARY_MONEY         MONEY,
       SALARY_SMALLMONEY    SMALLMONEY,        
       BIRTHDATE            DATE,       
       HIREDATE_DATETIME    DATETIME,
       JOIN_TIME            TIME,
       JOINTIME             DATETIME) 




insert into GroovyExps_Tgt values(000080,'LEE','B','BRETT',11111111.11111111,
11111111.11111111,11111111.11111111,
11111111.11111111,11111111.11111111,
11111111.11111111,'1985-05-10',
'2014-04-22 20:25:48.002','20:25','2014-04-22 20:25:48.002')
```

> Error:
>
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting numeric to data type smallmoney. The statement has been
>   terminated.

I need to insert exact data into table without any change in table definition!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, this error happens when converting a character or string value, whether of char, varchar, nchar or nvarchar data type, into a smallmoney data type and the character value has invalid characters that cannot be converted to smallmoney data type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that value 11,111,111 exceeds smallmoney's maximum allowed value which is between - 214,748.3648 and 214,748.3647. For more details you can refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx

It is not possible to insert that value in that table without changing its definition, using the money data type yo can accomplish it... could you please tell me what you are trying to accomplish there, so I may help you better?

Comment: what should i do to fit that value into table..
is it possible with smallmoney(max) or should I use only money data type to accomplish this..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

> As per your insert statement 11111111.11111111 this value you are
>   using as a smallmoney value. Smallmoney datatype takes **4 bytes** to
>   store the **value in range of -214,748.3648 to +214,748.3647**. Now you
>   see you are using large value for smallmoney that's why it's giving
>   you error.